# Resolve Error in MVC 4 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

in .cs files when you encounter errors like "The type or namespace name 'Products' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

you right click it and select resolve to automatically add missing assembly references. in razor .cshtml, how do you do this?

Comment: You use ReSharper if you want the same functionality for views.

Answer (score 1):

You add a `using` statement to your razor view.

```
@using YourNameSpaceIfExists.Products
```

If you do not wish to type the full path(NamespaceName.className) in each view you want to use this class, you can globally add those namespace to the **web.config available in the Views folder**. You will see a namespaces secrion under pages section. Add your namespace to the l

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      <add namespace="YourNameSpaceNameHere"/>
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Now in your views, you can simply use the class name

```
@model Product
```

Comment: so like the Model to typecast it i need to type something like `@model System.Linq.IQueryable`? is there any "automated" way to do it? or i really need to type it manually?

Comment: @Joe: I do not understand what you mean. Can you be more specific and detail ?

Comment: i've edited my previous comment, forgot that pressing enter submits the form.